# h1 properties being overridden

Tags: html, css

I am taking on somebody's ASP.NET MVC 5 project, and playing around with some of the HTML and CSS code. In `Site.css`, I have the following code:

```
h1
{
    color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    font-size: 100pt;
    font-family: 'Baskerville Old Face', Garamond, serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

However, when I run the program and inspect the elements, I notice the `h1` that I have in my HTML file is not displayed as I have defined above. Instead, the `color` and `font-size` properties seem to revert to their default. In the inspector in Firefox, these properties are crossed out as in this screenshot:
[image: inspector]

What could be the cause of this? I'm assuming that it is something which the previous owner of the project has set up, but unfortunately he is now unavailable. So I'm just looking for ideas as to what may be the root of this behaviour?

Comment: Watch line numbers. that h1 tag is matched by more than one CSS rule (line 77, line 70 and line 17 - the one you're inspecting)

Comment: site.css:77 has to be corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your css code is in the wrong order - as your style is before the other style (yours is on line 17 and the other styles are on line 70 and 77), the second lot will override the first lot. Put your style after the h1 style on line 77 in the site.css and yours will take precedence.

[This is a good article about css precedence and specificity](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/) - in your case, see the cascade section (point 4):

If two rules are equal, the one declared last wins. CSS embedded in the html always come after external stylesheets regardless of the order in the html

Answer (score 4):

this is because css in casscade stylesheet. So you new h1 should be on the end of file.css
First style h1 from line 17 will be overridden by the last from line 77

Answer (score 2):

If you want to override the others CSS add   !important in your Code
like this

```
h1
{
    color: rgb(255, 0, 0)!important;
    font-size: 100pt!important;
    font-family: 'Baskerville Old Face', Garamond, serif!important;
    font-weight: bold!important;
    font-style: italic!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
body h1 {
    color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    font-size: 100pt;
}
```

You need to reach a higher herarchy in the css.
So adding a parent to the `h1` you want to change it will work.
Or another way to achieve it is pasting your `h1` code after the `h1` that is overwriting your `h1` code. Paste it after line 77 and will work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove  Properties `color & font-size` from  H1 statement from  line  70 & 77  ( site.css) yo will find something like

```
h1,h2,h3,h4{color:#000...
```

convert to `h2,h3,h4{color:#000....`